# If a Questioner happens to mention they are from India, does that mean the question is India-specific?

Tags: discussion

[How can I effectively request to reduce the number of Hours I work per week](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11887/is-it-normal-to-expect-a-software-company-to-allow-me-to-work-two-hours-less-per)

Am I missing something here?

Just because the writer mentions that she is from India, must all answers be framed with in-depth knowledge of India? Or is a more useful answer one that helps folks worldwide?

Comment: @Joe [CC](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/if-a-questioner-happens-to-mention-they-are-from-india-does-that-mean-the-quest#comment2630_1862)

Comment: @JeffO (and CC others) meta up/downvotes mean more agree or disagree rather than directly representing the quality of the question/answer.

Comment: @enderland - In that case, I don't think I understand the disagreement. How do you agree or disagree with a question (as opposed to a statement)? "Am I missing something here?" = disagree? "Just because the writer mentions that she is from India, must all answers be framed with in-depth knowledge of India?" = disagree? "Or is a more useful answer one that helps folks worldwide?" = disagree?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm not sure, I've not voted on it myself :) In this case I imagine people are voting based on whether they agree with, "should this question NOT require an answer culturally relevant to India?"

Comment: Thanks @enderland. I'm still confused. It's like if I asked my granddaughter if she wanted a red popsicle or a green popsicle, and she said "I disagree". It would be good for a laugh, but not a very useful response otherwise. I guess it will remain a (meta) mystery.

Comment: Joe, I think what @enderland might be getting at is that it's quite obvious which opinion you hold, and voters may be disagreeing with that.  It's definitely *not* the same thing as asking "red or green", since you came here to defend your position on a question you answered.  I don't think the subtext is lost on voters.

Comment: So rather than a vote on the question being asked here on Meta, you think people are voting on the Main site question? I see.

Answer (score 4):

Big difference culturally between western culture and India, which is relevant to the workplace as well. India tends to be much less direct culturally, so one example would be going to your boss saying "this is a problem how can we fix it." this may be received incredibly poorly as compared to in a US workplace, where such behavior is encouraged.

There are also all sorts of differences in work environment and expectations for employees. Working hours are different, etc.

There just are lots of differences. Answering with an American/western perspective sometimes will completely miss these differences. Just search google for differences in American/Indian workplace culture/expectations. My understanding is the general *trend* is for companies in India to be striving to "match" western culture but this is not even remotely "done" obviously.

I also think the job market is far more competitive than in the USA, though I'm not sure.

---

Sometimes there is not a one-size-fits-all answer. See [this meta question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/578/how-can-we-ensure-answers-are-culturally-relevant) too.

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7258/should-we-tell-all-performance-related-problems-to-manager) is an example where applying a USA centric perspective could very easily do serious damage to someone's career. If you spend time trying to learn the cultural differences, you will see how different India culturally treats feedback than the USA.

Comment: Chad, Joe: [get a room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Chad, Joe, I have read and cleaned up the comments.  I can see that this is something you both feel passionately about.  However, let's not devolve into bickering in comments.  As Yannis has suggested [chat] is an appropriate forum for working this out, one which I hope you will utilize.

Comment: excellent perspective, suggestion and addressing of an edge-case.