# Tag Merge: software-development into software-industry

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

**Proposal: merge [software-development](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) into [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry)**

Stats:

- [software-development](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development)

  - **Questions**: 140
  - **Tag Info**: [blank]
- [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry)

  - **Questions**: 1,405
  - **Tag Info**: *Questions with this tag should be specific to the Software Industry, or to workplace elements commonly associated with said industry. The Software Industry deals with the creation, maintenance, and distribution of software. In addition, the creation of any associated training/documentation, as well as any consulting work, is included under the auspices of Software Industry.*
- [**Questions tagged with both**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development+software-industry): 53

---

Note that the [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry) tag itself [has previously been a subject of discussion.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/software-industry-tag-discussion)

Comment: I wonder what percentage of those ~1500 questions are actually __specific__ to the software industry :(

Comment: Where does that leave maintenance coders and systems programmers?

Comment: Why not just burniate the software-development tag?  Its not really appropriate here in the first place. (geniune question btw)

Comment: @RichardU Neither is covered by either tag at the moment. I think it might be worth revisiting the discussion on the merits (or otherwise) of that tag but this thread is mainly just to get rid of [tag:software-development].

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings If you mean burninate the one and keep the other, then, as a software developer, I can certainly see someone try to tag their software-industry-specific question with [tag:software-development] instead (but I don't think it would make a big difference whether we make them synonyms or retag all questions over to [tag:software-industry], apart from [tag:software-development] potentially popping up again once in a while). If you mean burn both, then [the post OP linked](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/software-industry-tag-discussion) is relevant.

Comment: @Dukeling - If you burniate the tag you the tag can not be used in the future and anyone trying to use that tag gets notified of this so they can choose a better tag.  Also it is a meta tag as any questin that is actually about software development belongs on software engineering and not here as this is the workplace, not programmers.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings AFAIK: Burninated tags can be recreated by anyone with the "create tags" privilege. Blacklisted tags can't be recreated, but that's a manual process that needs to be done by SE employees (not just mods) and is usually reserved for tags that just won't die.

Comment: When you burniate the tag it is also black listed as a tag not to be used again.... Its something mods can do, all we can do is remove the tag from the questions or retag them approirately.  Which is why i asked why we dont just burniate the tag instead of merging.